# Call thread from service

Tags: android, multithreading, service

Can I start threads from service?

I want to record ongoing audio signals and detect whistle in my app, this should run even after the app is closed. For this app, I have two threads, one is continuously recording the audio and other is detecting the whistle(i have used the code from [musicg](https://code.google.com/p/musicg/) library). Now I am using service so that this entire functionality always runs in the background, service is calling these two threads as shown in the code below.
Issue: Once the app is started and service is started, if I close the app, it is throwing an error.

Code:

```
`package com.musicg.demo.android;

import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class DetectAndLockService extends Service implements
        OnSignalsDetectedListener {

    private DetectorThread detectorThread;
    private RecorderThread recorderThread;
    private DevicePolicyManager deviceManger;
    private ActivityManager activityManager;
    private ComponentName compName;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        deviceManger = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
        activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        compName = new ComponentName(this, MyAdmin.class);

        if (VariableClass.get_detection_running()) {
            recorderThread = new RecorderThread();
            recorderThread.start();
            detectorThread = new DetectorThread(recorderThread);
            detectorThread.setOnSignalsDetectedListener(DetectAndLockService.this);
            detectorThread.start();
        } else {
            recorderThread.stopRecording();
            detectorThread.stopDetection();
        }
        return (START_STICKY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWhistleDetected() {       

         /*Action to be performed*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        recorderThread.stopRecording();
        detectorThread.stopDetection();     
        System.out.println("Service is destroyed");
    }


}
`
```

LogCat:

```
`
11-27 17:01:14.843: W/dalvikvm(6206): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409f41f8)
11-27 17:01:14.853: E/AndroidRuntime(6206): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-27 17:01:14.853: E/AndroidRuntime(6206): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.musicg.demo.android.DetectAndLockService@4105d438 with null: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-27 17:01:14.853: E/AndroidRuntime(6206):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2376)
11-27 17:01:14.853: E/AndroidRuntime(6206):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:123)
11-27 17:01:14.853: E/AndroidRuntime(6206):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
11-27 17:01:14.853: E/AndroidRuntime(6206):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-27 17:01:14.853: E/AndroidRuntime(6206):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-27 17:01:14.853: E/AndroidRuntime(6206):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
11-27 17:01:14.853: E/AndroidRuntime(6206):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-27 17:01:14.853: E/AndroidRuntime(6206):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-27 17:01:14.853: E/AndroidRuntime(6206):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
11-27 17:01:14.853: E/AndroidRuntime(6206):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
11-27 17:01:14.853: E/AndroidRuntime(6206):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-27 17:01:14.853: E/AndroidRuntime(6206): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-27 17:01:14.853: E/AndroidRuntime(6206):     at com.musicg.demo.android.DetectAndLockService.onStartCommand(DetectAndLockService.java:52)
11-27 17:01:14.853: E/AndroidRuntime(6206):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2359)
11-27 17:01:14.853: E/AndroidRuntime(6206):     ... 10 more

`
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have you considered using IntentService??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `VariableClass.get_detection_running()` method return `false` then you are not checking for `null` or initializing both `recorderThread` and `detectorThread` instances before calling methods. so you are getting `NullPointerException`do it as:

```
    if (VariableClass.get_detection_running()) {
        ///...your code here..
    } else {
        if(null !=recorderThread)
        recorderThread.stopRecording();
        if(null !=detectorThread
        detectorThread.stopDetection();
    }
```

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K, thanks for the help, after changing as you asked it is not throwing the error when I close the app when service is running. Now the problem is, after closing the app, the service has stopped detecting whistle!!

Answer (score 0):

You must you `AsyncTask` to perform this.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

You must reimplement the `doInBackground` method.

Comment: I dont want to deal with UI, still AsyncTask is advisable?

Comment: Of course. You are expected to use it following the Android guidelines.